# Is there a way to change the Apache error log file via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I'm hosting a website in a shared host, but I'm getting the 500 error.
Well, I don't have access to the Apache error log file to investigate the cause of the problem.

Is there a way to change the location of the Apache error log file via .htaccess to a dir that I can access it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

According to the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog) the context for the `ErrorLog` directive is *server config, virtual host*. It would list *.htaccess* if it were possible.

You may have a better chance at redirecting output through the server-side technology. But the best thing to do would be to contact your host. Access to *your* error log should be allowed.

Comment: Thanks, I've contacted the support and the problem was solved.